# Counter-intuitive git rm --cached flag behavior when invoked via git filter-branch (retroactive .gitignore)

Tags: git

### Question

What difference does the `--cached` flag make when running `git rm` via `git filter-branch --index-filter`?

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached *.ext'  
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm *.ext'
```

---

### Issue

When I run `git rm --cached *.ext`, all `*.ext` files are un-tracked **but not** removed from working directory (this is the purpose of `--cached` flag as I understand it)

**But**, when I try to run that command retroactively like

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached *.ext'`

all historical `*.ext` files are un-tracked **AND** existing `*.ext` files **ARE** removed from working directory.

Why?

What's the difference without `--cached`

### Theory

Since the command is being run on all commits, with no "working directory" per run, it is also treating HEAD/current working directory as a standalone commit without a working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theory is mostly right, just a bit off at the very end.  `git filter-branch` doesn't use the standard index, nor your work-tree.  When it invokes each of your filters, it's running in a temporary directory whose location in the file system depends on whether you supplied a `-d directory` option.<sup>1</sup>  With no usable work-tree, all index-filter `git rm` operations *should* use `--cached`.<sup>2</sup>  Filter-branch also creates a temporary index within the temporary directory.  This temporary index is in place for each step of the filtering: it's used to extract the commit for the index filter, and then to make the new commit after the index-filter modifies it.

Having finished all the filtering operations, the last few steps of `filter-branch` are:

1. Update all the to-be-modified references: the filtered branches, and any tags if you used `--tag-name-filter`.  For instance, `master` might have identified commit `a123456...` before.  If new commit `b789abc...` is the one that should now be used instead of `a123456`, Git must rewrite `refs/heads/master` so that it now identifies commit `b789abc...`.
2. If you're in a non-bare repository (filter-branch *can* be used on bare repositories), effectively `git checkout` the new commit instead of the old one.  This updates your index and work-tree, so that your index and work-tree remain "clean".<sup>3</sup>  The actual operation is a `git read-tree`:

   ```
   if [ "$(is_bare_repository)" = false ]; then
           git read-tree -u -m HEAD || exit
   fi
   ```

**It's this last step, the effective-check-out, that removes your `*.ext` files.**

Your *current* index shows them as *tracked*, which they are; they're in your current *commit*, which is (say) `a123456...`.  Your new target commit `b789abc...` lacks the `*.ext` files, because you filtered them away with your `--index-filter`.  So to move from the current commit to the new commit, the correct operation is to remove the files.

**To fix the problem:**

Run `git rm --cached '*.ext'` *before* you run the filter-branch command with the `--index-filter` option, and commit.  That way your *current* commit (which will no longer be `a123456...`) *won't* have the files, and your index won't have the files, so they'll just be untracked files in both the current commit and the new one and will be untouched.

---

<sup>1</sup>Filter-branch starts by setting `$tempdir` from your `-d` option, or the default, which is `.git-rewrite`.  It then creates `$tempdir/t`, creating `$tempdir` too if needed; changes location into it; and sets the Git work-tree to `.`.  This `$tempdir/t` directory remains empty unless you use the `--tree-filter` option or, in any of your filters, attempt to manipulate the current directory in some way.

<sup>2</sup>Without `--cached`, `git rm` tries to remove files from `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, i.e., `$tempdir/t`.  Filter-branch's own state files are in `../` from here, i.e., in `$tempdir`, so they should be safe in general, but it's still not a great idea to try to remove things that shouldn't be there anyway: if nothing else, it's wasted compute time.  Using `--cached` keeps `git rm` from even attempting it.

<sup>3</sup>"Clean" here is a vaguely-defined state that you probably recognize anyway.  The precise definition, if you want it, is in [`git-sh-setup.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh), specifically in the function [`require_clean_work_tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017/git-sh-setup.sh#L211).  Filter-branch invokes this before beginning the filtering, if run on a non-bare repository.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer!  It seems, that in my case, (I don't want an additional "commit" to remove historical files, but I also want to keep the files in working tree), I should wait until I'm ready to make another substantive commit, run `git rm --cached '*.ext'` before finally committing, and then run the `git filter-tree --index-filter...` command?

Comment: You *can* wait but that makes it easy to forget. I'd suggest instead: Go ahead and make the extra commit. Do the filter-branch and make sure you're happy with the results. Then, remove the extra commit you made (and that Git copied) with `git reset --hard HEAD^`, if Git copied it. Note that `--filter-branch` has a `--prune-empty` option that skips making a commit if it matches a previous one, which is useful for these particular cases as long as you don't have deliberate "empty" commits that you want to preserve.

Comment: Does tree-filter behavior differ with regards to --cached?  It seems the flag doesn't accomplish anything in that case.

Comment: [Here is another question I've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57418769), if you're interested in taking a look.

Comment: `tree-filter` is very different, because it throws away any changes you make to the index and builds a new commit strictly from whatever you leave in the temporary directory.

Comment: I saw that earlier, and really don't want to wade into that. I think you'll find that this gets messy no matter how you do it: it turns out people don't always want their `.gitignore` files being obeyed.

Comment: understood, thanks VERY MUCH, you helped me come up with my answer to that q, specifically committing immediately after `rm -cached`, and then a `--prune-empty` on the following `git filter-branch` command.  Incredibly helpful!