# Definitive retroactive .gitignore (how to make Git completely/retroactively *forget* about a file now in .gitignore)

Tags: git, gitignore

### Preface

This question attempts to clear the confusion regarding applying .gitignore **retroactively**, not just to the present/future.<sup>1</sup>

### Rationale

I've been searching for a way to make my current .gitignore be retroactively enforced, **as if I had created .gitignore in the first commit**.

The solution I am seeking:

- Will *not* require manually specifying files
- Will *not* require a commit
- Will apply retroactively to all commits of all branches
- Will *ignore* .gitignore-specified files in working dir, **not delete** them (just like an originally root-committed .gitignore file would)
- Will use git, not BFG
- Will apply to .gitignore exceptions like:

```
 *.ext
 !*special.ext
```

---

### Not solutions

```
git rm --cached *.ext
git commit
```

This requires 1. manually specifying files and 2. an additional commit, which will result in newly-ignored file *deletion* when pulled by other developers. (It is effectively just a `git rm` - which is a *deletion* from git tracking - but it leaves the file alone in the local (*your*) working directory.  *Others* who `git pull` afterwards will receive the file *deletion* commit)

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached *.ext'
```

While this *does* purge files retroactively, it 1. requires manually specifying files and 2. [*deletes* the specified files from the **local** working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419809/423125) just like plain `git rm` (and so also for others who `git pull`)!

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>There are many similar posts here on SO, with less-than-specifically-defined questions and even more less-than-accurate answers. See [this question with 23 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057) where the [accepted answer with ~4k votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447) is **incorrect** according to the standard definition of "forget" [as noted by one mostly-correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56051380), and [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274126/423125) 2 [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56051380/423125) include the ***required*** `git filter-branch` command.

[This question with 21 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936249/423125) <strike>is</strike> was marked as a duplicate of the previous one, but the question is defined differently (ignore vs forget), so while the answers may be appropriate, it is **not** a duplicate.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43463687) is the closest I've found to what I'm looking for, but the answers don't work in all cases (paths with spaces...) and perhaps are a bit more complex than necessary regarding creating an external-to-repository .gitignore file and copying it into every commit.

Comment: Sometimes it's just better to write a script to do the manual things for you.

Comment: Is your goal to rewrite the repository to how it would look if the files in question _were never committed_ (which would invalidate all existing commit IDs, and probably break things for every existing clone/checkout of the repo), or to configure your local working directory such that Git _pretends_ those files are not present in an old commit when you check it out?

Comment: Goal is the former, "as if I had created .gitignore at the beginning". I understand the ramifications, but my repo is local/private and I don't mind a force-push.  Although feel free to specify how to handle the latter if you answer - seems it would be useful information.

Comment: If you understand the ramification and your repo is local/private, it means that you intend to use a system built with the intention to be shared (or enable collaboration) within a problem that denies the need for collaboration or authorship (that's what you do when you invalidate the IDs ... you basically don't care who did what. If this is onetime thingy, I presume it is fine, but then I would agree [@Henning Makholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882051/henning-makholm)

Comment: I'm a git noob, and I can't imagine I'm the only one who has started to learn git on a local repo and forgotten to start with a .gitignore - the number of "how to make .gitignore actually ignore..." questions here seems to confirm my suspicion.  It seems git needs a "found new changes to gitignore file - would you like to ignore these files 1 - never (default), 2 - present/future, or 3 - past/present/future - warning: don't do this with shared repos that have pull requests" feature. It's clear GitHub Desktop is catering to the noob crowd, so seems not-unreasonable for such a feature to exist

Comment: Specific to my scenario, I have need for proper version control of an internal project that only I manage, with no reason to ever be shared with the public. Shared internally at some point, sure, but needs quite a bit of work before then. Prior 'version control' method relies on editor's default "copy old version to .BAK file" behavior and twice-daily Volume Shadow Copy snapshots on windows file server. I want something better.

Comment: Also, its unclear what you're agreeing with [@Henning Makholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882051/henning-makholm) about, don't think he stated an opinion.

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me _why_ you feel a need to rewrite old commits. What will you get out of that, rather than just have things right going forward?

Comment: A "clean" repo from the start without junk/binary files.  Same reason anyone creates a .gitignore file I would assume.

Comment: There are MANY such posts here on SO, with less-than-specifically-defined questions and even more less-than-accurate accepted answers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057) with 23 answers where the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447) (with ~4k votes) is WRONG according to the standard definition of "forget", and only 3 answers mention the required `git filter-branch` command. Not sure why the downvotes for a specifically defined question designed to eliminate less-than-accurate answers.

Comment: It's going to be like a five-line `filter-branch`, tops. Put your exclusions in `.git/info/exclude`, do a `git ls-files --exclude-standard -ci` and rm --cached them.

Comment: thanks for the `.git/info/exclude` tip!

Comment: Regarding the edit, I'll give way on the preface, even though I think the wording of "forget" includes "retroactively". But please do not use quote blocks as a general highlighter - quote blocks are for quotes.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree that forget=retroactively, and would have no need to specify it explicitly, if not for the other incredibly upvoted “completely forget” question with an accepted answer that only applies to the present/future.  Perhaps that question should be edited to be more explicit (present/future only) as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be only a partial answer but here is how I accomplished retroactively removing files from previous git commits based on my current .gitignore file:

1. Make a backup of the repo folder you are working on. I just made a .7z archive of the entire folder.
2. Install [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)
3. Copy your .gitignore file somewhere else temporarily. Since I'm on Windows and using Command Prompt, I ran `copy .gitignore ..\` and just made the temp copy only directory level up
4. If your .gitignore file has wildcard filters (like `nbproject/Makefile-*`), you'll need to edit your temp copied .gitignore file so those lines read `glob:nbproject/Makefile-*`
5. Run `git filter-repo --invert-paths --paths-from-file ..\.gitignore`. My understanding is that this uses the temp copy as a list of files/directories to remove. Note: if you receive an error regarding your repo not being a clean clone, search for "FRESH CLONE SAFETY CHECK AND --FORCE" in the git-filter-repo help. Be careful.

For more info see:
[git-filter-repo help](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) (Search for "Filtering based on many paths")

Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm doing but this worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: I've recently found [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).  It may be a better choice.  Perhaps a good idea to investigate the [rationale](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#why-filter-repo-instead-of-other-alternatives) and filter-branch [gotchas](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#SAFETY) for yourself, but they wouldn't have affected my use-case below.

---

This method makes Git **completely forget** ignored files (**past**/present/future), but does **not** delete anything from working directory (even when re-pulled from remote).

This method requires usage of `/.git/info/exclude` (preferred) **OR** a **pre-existing** `.gitignore` in **all** the commits that have files to be ignored/forgotten. <sup>1</sup>

This method **avoids** removing the newly-ignored files from other developers machines on the next `git pull` <sup>2</sup>

*All* methods of enforcing Git ignore behavior after-the-fact effectively re-write history and thus have [significant ramifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001) for any public/shared/collaborative repos that might be pulled after this process. <sup>3</sup>

General advice: **start with a clean repo** - everything committed, nothing pending in working directory or index, **and make a backup**!

Also, the comments/[revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57454176/revisions) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454176) ([and revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57418769/revisions) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57418769)) may be useful/enlightening.

```sh
#commit up-to-date .gitignore (if not already existing)
#these commands must be run on each branch
#these commands are not strictly necessary if you don't want/need a .gitignore file.  .git/info/exclude can be used instead

git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Create .gitignore"

#apply standard git ignore behavior only to current index, not working directory (--cached)
#if this command returns nothing, ensure /.git/info/exclude AND/OR .gitignore exist
#this command must be run on each branch
#if using .git/info/exclude, it will need to be modified per branch run, if the branches have differing (per-branch) .gitignore requirements.

git ls-files -z --ignored --exclude-standard | xargs -r0 git rm --cached

#Commit to prevent working directory data loss!
#this commit will be automatically deleted by the --prune-empty flag in the following command
#this command must be run on each branch
#optionally use the --amend flag to merge this commit with the previous one instead of creating 2 commits.

git commit -m "ignored index"

#Apply standard git ignore behavior RETROACTIVELY to all commits from all branches (--all)
#This step WILL delete ignored files from working directory UNLESS they have been dereferenced from the index by the commit above
#This step will also delete any "empty" commits.  If deliberate "empty" commits should be kept, remove --prune-empty and instead run git reset HEAD^ immediately after this command

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git ls-files -z --ignored --exclude-standard | xargs -r0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

#List all still-existing files that are now ignored properly
#if this command returns nothing, it's time to restore from backup and start over
#this command must be run on each branch

git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard
```

---

Finally, follow the rest of [this GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) (starting at step 6) **which includes important warnings/information about the commands below**.

```sh
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
git for-each-ref --format="delete %(refname)" refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

---

Other devs that pull from now-modified remote repo should make a backup and then:

```sh
#fetch modified remote

git fetch --all

#"Pull" changes WITHOUT deleting newly-ignored files from working directory
#This will overwrite local tracked files with remote - ensure any local modifications are backed-up/stashed

git reset FETCH_HEAD
```

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Because `/.git/info/exclude` can be applied to all historical commits using the instructions above, perhaps details about getting a `.gitignore` file *into* the historical commit(s) that need it is beyond the scope of this answer.  I wanted a proper `.gitignore` to be in the root commit, as if it was the first thing I did.  Others may not care since `/.git/info/exclude` can accomplish the same thing regardless where the `.gitignore` exists in the commit history, and clearly re-writing history is a **very** touchy subject, even when aware of the [ramifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001).

FWIW, potential methods may include `git rebase` or a `git filter-branch` that copies an *external* `.gitignore` into each commit, like the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43463687)

<sup>2</sup> Enforcing git ignore behavior after-the-fact by committing the results of a standalone `git rm --cached` command may result in newly-ignored file **deletion** in future pulls from the force-pushed remote. The `--prune-empty` flag in the `git filter-branch` command (*or* `git reset HEAD^` afterwards) avoids this problem by automatically removing the previous "delete all ignored files" index-only commit.

<sup>3</sup> Re-writing git history also changes commit hashes, which will [wreak havoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001) on future pulls from public/shared/collaborative repos.  Please understand the [ramifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001) fully before doing this to such a repo. [This GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) specifies the following:

> Tell your collaborators to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing), *not* merge, any branches they created off of your old (tainted) repository history. One merge commit could reintroduce some or all of the tainted history that you just went to the trouble of purging.

Alternative solutions that **do not** affect the remote repo are `git update-index --assume-unchanged </path/file>` or `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>`, examples of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241145).

Comment: I had hoped to use `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -z --ignored --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs -0 git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` instead, but got `fatal: cannot use .gitignore as an exclude file`

Comment: Couple potential .gitignore "injection" solutions - git rebase..., or git-filter-branch that copies external .gitignore into every commit like the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43463687/423125)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Windows because of `xargs`.

Comment: This was developed/tested on windows Git - use it in Cygwin (Git Bash), not CMD.

Comment: If you just want to delete this eclipse .project file that you accidentally committed very recently, then `git-filter-repo` is ridiculously oversized for the task. I ran `git-filter-repo --analyze`, opened the folder where it wrote the analysis result, and I am absolutely, completely intimidated. Using `git-filter-repo` looks an order of magnitude harder than doing the few required actions completely by hand, as in checkout master, checkout -b feex, fix .gitignore, checkout topic, rebase -i feex.